# Why does AVAudioPlayer not work when button pressed?

Tags: arrays, sorting, swiftui, avaudioplayer

VIew:

```
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

struct SutraView: View {
    private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    private mutating  func playAVAudio(text: String) {
        
        guard let audioFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Mokugyo", ofType: "mp3") else {
            return
        }
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioFilePath))
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

class SutraViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    private let sutraText: String // text form Model
    private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    @Published var itemsToShow: AttributedString? // what  will show
    @Published var currentIndex: Int = 0
    
    // MARK: - Initialization for SutraModel
    init(model: SutraModel) {
        self.sutraText = model.sutraText
    
    }
    
    // MARK: - Public methods
    func buttonDidPressed() {
        currentIndex += 1
        highlightCurrentWord(text: sutraText)
    }
    
    // MARK: Private methods
    private func highlightCurrentWord(text: String) {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: sutraText) // string can containe design
        let itemsArray = sutraText.createArrayOfWords()
        
        if currentIndex < itemsArray.count {
            let wordsWithSpaces = sutraText.split(separator: " ")
            var characterCount = 0
            for index in 0..<currentIndex {
                characterCount += wordsWithSpaces[index].count + 1
            }
            let range = NSRange(location: characterCount, length: itemsArray[currentIndex].count)
            //attributedString.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.green, range: range)
            attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: range)
            
            let currentWord = itemsArray[currentIndex]
            if currentWord.contains("*") {
                audioPlayer?.play()
            }
        }
        self.itemsToShow = AttributedString(attributedString)
    }
}
```

When you press button "Next" and the text cursor goes through asterisk "*" music has to play, but it does't work.

Comment: I don't see any `button "Next"` in your code, maybe you forgot to show the important parts of your question. In any case, show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It looks like you have a `AVAudioPlayer` in your view and a unrelated one in your `SutraViewModel`.

Comment: I have button "Next",  func buttonDidPressed() {
    currentIndex += 1
    highlightCurrentWord(text: sutraText) goes through array and higlighs words, but player does not working :  let currentWord = itemsArray[currentIndex]
        if currentWord.contains("*") {
            audioPlayer?.play() thas has to go through asterisk.
}

Comment: how/where do you set the `audioPlayer` of your `SutraViewModel` ? Currently it is nil. Show the code for `SutraView`

Comment: Yes, you are right audioPlayer is nill.

Comment: Currently your `SutraView` view has not the required `var body: some View {...}` and does not have 
 a `SutraViewModel`. Without knowing 
 the **very basics** of SwiftUI, you are going to struggle coding your app and understand any answers.
 Learn a bit more about SwiftUI, such as for example: [SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/). 
Also have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app: 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).